# denoising binary image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

For my project i'm trying to binarize an image with openCV in python. I used the adaptive gaussian thresholding from openCV to convert the image with the following result:
[image]

I want to use the binary image for OCR but it's too noisy. Is there any way to remove the noise from the binary image in python? I already tried fastNlMeansDenoising from openCV but it doesn't make a difference.

P.S better options for binarization are welcome as well

Comment: u can use bigger constant argument for cv2.adaptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by adjusting the parameters to the adaptive threshold so it uses a larger area. That way it won't be segmenting out noise. Whenever your output image has more noise than the input image, you know you're doing something wrong.

I suggest as an adaptive threshold to use a closing (on the input grey-value image) with a structuring element just large enough to remove all the text. The difference between this result and the input image is exactly all the text. You can then apply a regular threshold to this difference.

Comment: I'm already using the adaptive thresholding, but I tried playing around with the variables which made a huge difference. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible using GraphCuts for this kind of task. You will need to install the [maxflow](http://pmneila.github.io/PyMaxflow/) library in order to run the code. I quickly copied the code from their [tutorial](http://pmneila.github.io/PyMaxflow/tutorial.html#tutorial) and modified it, so you could run it more easily. Just play around with the smoothing parameter to increase or decrease the denoising of the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import maxflow 

# Important parameter
# Higher values means making the image smoother
smoothing = 110

# Load the image and convert it to grayscale image 
image_path = 'your_image.png'
img = cv2.imread('image_path')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = 255 * (img > 128).astype(np.uint8)

# Create the graph.
g = maxflow.Graph[int]()
# Add the nodes. nodeids has the identifiers of the nodes in the grid.
nodeids = g.add_grid_nodes(img.shape)
# Add non-terminal edges with the same capacity.
g.add_grid_edges(nodeids, smoothing)
# Add the terminal edges. The image pixels are the capacities
# of the edges from the source node. The inverted image pixels
# are the capacities of the edges to the sink node.
g.add_grid_tedges(nodeids, img, 255-img)

# Find the maximum flow.
g.maxflow()
# Get the segments of the nodes in the grid.
sgm = g.get_grid_segments(nodeids)

# The labels should be 1 where sgm is False and 0 otherwise.
img_denoised = np.logical_not(sgm).astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Show the result.
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Binary image')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Denoised binary image')
plt.imshow(img_denoised, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Save denoised image
cv2.imwrite('img_denoised.png', img_denoised)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXya8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the morphological transformation close to remove small "holes".
First define a kernel using numpy, you might need to play around with the size. Choose the size of the kernel as big as your noise.

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
```

Then run the morphologyEx using the kernel.

```
denoised = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

If text gets removed you can try to erode the image, this will "grow" the black pixels. If the noise is as big as the data, this method will not help.

```
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like your approach but it's not really working for this image. But I already found another method to binarize the image named Sauvola threshold

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was afraid this could not work, the image is pretty noisy. Sauvola threshold looks promising, i will try that too!